# How can I ignore the VSTest err msgs in my Windows Store app?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, vstest

When I build my Windows Store App, it shows me output from Tests:

```
------ Discover test started ------
Failed to configure settings for runsettings plugin 'VSTest Run Configuration' as it threw following exception:
'An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 8.'
Please contact the plugin author.
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.1350029) ==========
```

- and at the bottom of the window I see, "*Unexpected error detected. Check the Tests Output Pane for details*"

I don't care about this or want to see it (for now, anyway). I haven't got any tests set up. How can I hush up the Test nazi?

### UPDATE

I don't know if there's a direct connection, but after installing the SQLite package updates for Windows 8 and then Windows 8.1, those weird, rogue, non-compilation-blocking "exception" messages went away.

As Kip Dynamite would say, "Dang it!!!" I wrote too soon; that same err msg is now back again.

### UPDATE 2

It seems that changing my package name on the Packaging tab of Package.appxmanifest from [some GUID] to [companyName.appName] solved it...butt Y?

### UPDATE 3

One time only (it's baaaaack!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just had this issue for the last day or so, preventing me from running the unit tests in my projects.

The error **An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 8.** is what you would get back from an `XmlReader` if there is an error parsing xml, for example unescaped characters.

In my case I had an **&** in a folder name at a higher level.  Renaming the folder then Build > Clean solution seems to have fixed the issue.